# Как условно изменить значения в столбце DataFrame (неитерационно)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Дан DataFrame с тремя колонками. Задача - в третьей колонке оставить неокругленными значения из второй, если в первой число нецелое; и обратно - в третью записать округленные значения из второй, если в первой целое число; причем сделать это нужно неитерацинно.
Ниже приведу безуспешные попытки решения; `concat` и `merge` не помогли (либо не до конца разобрался):

Вариант 1. Делал так, однако, видимо, атрибут `inplace` для метода `pandas.DataFrame.round` отсутствует:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Am1'] = [1, 2.5, 4, 6.8]
df['Am2'] = df['Am1'] * 1.05
df['Am3'] = df['Am2']
df[df['Am2'] % 1 == 0]['Am3'].round(0)
```

Вариант 2.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Am1'] = [1, 2.5, 4, 6.8]
df['Am2'] = df['Am1'] * 1.05
df['Am3'] = df['Am2']
df['Am3'] = df[df['Am1'] % 1 == 0]['Am3'].round(0)
```

Вариант 3.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Am1'] = [1, 2.5, 4, 6.8]
df['Am2'] = df['Am1'] * 1.05
df['Am3'] = df.loc[df['Am1'] % 1 == 0, 'Am2'].round()
df['Am3'] += df.loc[df['Am1'] % 1 != 0, 'Am2']
```

Вариант 4.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Am1'] = [1, 2.5, 4, 6.8]
df['Am2'] = df['Am1'] * 1.05
df['Am3'] = df.loc[df['Am1'] % 1 == 0, 'Am2'].round().fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['Am3'] += df.loc[df['Am1'] % 1 != 0, 'Am2'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Приведу решение с итерациями, чтобы был понятен ожидаемый результат:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Am1'] = [1, 2.5, 4, 6.8]
df['Am2'] = df['Am1'] * 1.05
df['Am3'] = df['Am2']
for i in df.index:
    if df.loc[i, 'Am1'] % 1 == 0:
        df.loc[i, 'Am3'] = df.loc[i, 'Am3'].round()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[df["Am1"] % 1 == 0, "Am3"] = df["Am3"].round()
```

---

результат:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   Am1    Am2    Am3
0  1.0  1.050  1.000
1  2.5  2.625  2.625
2  4.0  4.200  4.000
3  6.8  7.140  7.140
```

Comment: Не совсем корректно, необходимо округлять по мат.правилам

Comment: @username1, исправил ответ